# What the meaning of "faster than you can say Indiana Jones"?

Tags: idioms

I met with "faster than you can say Indiana Jones" like following:
*Now, faster than you can say Indiana Jones, Spielberg has changed course, leaving behind the place where he made such classics as E.T. the Extra-Terrestrial, Jaws, and Jurassic Park.* 
I searched the web and some english dictionaris , couldn't figure it out.Now who could lend me a hand?

Comment: We might think it would take a long time for a film director to change the way he makes films. But how long does it take you to say the two words "Indiana Jones"? It doesn't take me long. So we can conclude that Spielberg changed his direction quickly. Of course, it doesn't take long to say most two word combination, but the author chose those two because it's the name of one of Spielberg's older films.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a paraphrase of the idiom *[faster than you can say Jack Robinson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jack_Robinson_%28mythical_person%29)*. The author has replaced the name for (slightly) humorous effect.

See also:
http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/before+you+can+say+Jack+Robinson
[Who is Jack Robinson?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/101012/who-is-jack-robinson)

Comment: Yep.  And many other words are substituted for "Jack Robinson".  "Spit", "pop psychology", "look out", "WorldWide Web", et al.

Comment: And, actually, "quicker than you can say" was more common than "faster than you can say" [up until about 1970](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=quicker+than+you+can+say%2C+faster+than+you+can+say&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cquicker%20than%20you%20can%20say%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfaster%20than%20you%20can%20say%3B%2Cc0).  (Not sure why the shift occurred, other than perhaps the latter was a "catch phrase" on some TV show.)